# How much time to get a 30 second time-lapse video on 30fps on 2 second intervals

Tags: timelapse, gopro

So I'm outside taking video of some storm clouds in Arizona. Anyways I am using GoPro time-lapse video mode. It's set at 2-second intervals and I believe GoPro time-lapse mode shoots at 30 FPS (Frames Per Second) in trying to figure out how much time I would need to be outside in order to get a 30-second video? If possible show me how to do the math.

Comment: Please don't use comments for answers.  Yes, this question is fairly basic, but it does require a (very basic) understanding of how video works.  That isn't something people inherently are born understanding.  That said, this is probably a bit borderline since it's looking to make a video, though I'm going to leave that one up to the community since time-lapse is kind of borderline between video and photo.

Comment: Perhaps you could read this and refine your question: http://bestlifeintheworld.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-gopro-time-lapse/ - also there are Android APPs that will do all the Calculations, including taking the Photos and turning them into a Video.

Comment: "If possible show me how to do the math." Is this homework for a class?

Answer (score 4):

30 frames per second for 30 seconds gives a need for 900 frames (30 * 30).

Taking 2 seconds for each frame gives 1800 seconds (900 * 2) or 30 minutes (1800 / 60).

You might have to add extra time for the exposure time of each shot unless that time is subtracted from the interval time. Or in other words, is it interval time from beginning of a shot to beginning of the next shot or is it from the end of a shot to the beginning of the next shot?